# Parsing JSON server response into JSON Array

Tags: java, json, arrays

I am using Java to parse a JSON response from a server.  My end goal is to have the data from results in an Array.  Currently I am using this to try and get the results:

```
JSONArray jArray = myResponse.getJSONArray("results");
```

This code fails because it is looking for an array of objects, rather than an array of strings:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value blah at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is my server's JSON Response:

```
{
  status: "OK",
  results: [
    "blah",
    "bleh",
    "blah"
  ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to get the "results" value into an array?  Or should I just write my own parser.

Thanks

---------- UPDATE ----------

Looks like my problem was actually occuring somewhere else, and not where the JSON attribute "results" was being converted into a JSONArray.

Sorry and thanks for the answers, they helped me realize I was looking in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be it. So you're probably trying to get JSONObject instead of String inside the results aarray.

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i=0; i<resultsArray.length(); i++)
    String resultString = resultsArray.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you will probably have more properties, than only the `String[] result`, I recommend to define a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) like this:

```
public class Dto {
    //of course you should have private fields and public setters/getters, but this is only a sample
    public String status;
    public List<String> results;//this can be also an array
}
```

And then in your code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Dto dto = mapper.readValue(inputDtoJson, Dto.class);//now in dto you have all the properties you need
```